# Can you specify the depth after a wildcard expression in find?

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I have a small script that works perfectly well, except that it tries and fails to read some files that I don't want it reading anyway. It has no operational impact except it takes more time to read those extra files.

```
find "$FIND_START" -type f -wholename "*/DAT/*.zip"  | while read -r SOURCE_FILE
do
    echo "Generating data from $SOURCE_FILE"
    java -jar \
        generator-0.2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
        $SOURCE_FILE $VARIATION $OUTPUT_DIR $NUM_GENERATE $SEED \
        > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt

done
```

The depth at which the `DAT/` folder is located is not guaranteed, or I think I could somehow use `maxdepth` argument.

However, I  know that all the `.zip` files are contained directly in the `DAT/` directory, not any sub-directories.

Is there a way to specify the depth after the wild card? If it matters, I'm on git bash for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-regex` instead of `-wholename` (which, BTW, is equivalent to the more portable `-path`).

```
find "$FIND_START" -type f -regex '.*/DAT/[^/]+\.zip'
```

`[^/]+` matches a sequence of characters that doesn't include `/`, so it won't match across subdirectories of `DAT`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation of the parts of the regex pattern and what they do.